# Localization of app in language that is not in "Language" list in Settings.app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, localization

Here is my issue:

[image]

I have 2 localizations - for English and for Bulgarian. I can't load Bulgarian languages, because it's not in "Language" list, and English is loaded even though the Region Format is set to "Bulgaria".

Is there a way to open my app with my bulgarian localization files or not?

Comment: I would appreciate some more information about this topic, could you please help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of at least iOS 8 you can change the order of languages in *Settings > General > Language and Region* under the heading **Preferred Language Order**.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is no native way of supporting Bulgarian if iOS doesn't support it. We have a similar problem in Wales with Welsh.

At the moment, I would recommend an in-app setting that switches the language manually, using a look up table. Perhaps this could also be activated by looking at [NSLocale currentLocale].